# Modificar variables de un formulario a otro

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un problema y es que cuando modifico una variable o tag de una etiqueta del formulario padre desde un formulario hijo, al cerrar el formulario hijo, la variable o tag del formulario padre pasa a tener el valor anterior, como si no se hubiese modificado.

Lo que hago es llamar al constructor del formulario padre desde el formulario hijo, pasandole el parametro y dicho parametro asignandolo a un tag de una etiqueta del formulario padre.

Formulario hijo

```
Form2 frm2;
frm2 = new Form2("false");
```

Formulario padre

```
public Form2(string mostradoMenu)
{
    menu.Tag = mostradoMenu;
}
```

PD: menu es una etiqueta del formulario padre

No encuentro nada referido a eso y no consigo solucionarlo. He probado con setters, getters y demás, y nada.

Si alguien lo sabe, sería de mucha ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, sin ver nada del código que estás usando es dificil poder ayudarte. Pero como indicación, me extraña mucho el problema que expones. Más que al cerrar el formulario hijo se _pierda_ el valor que este puso, es más probable que en el formulario padre en algun momento se esté modificando ese valor.

Comment: Es normal porque al formulario hijo (supongo que lo pasas por parámetro al constructor) no envías el objeto sino una copia. Has pensado en utilizar eventos? Sigue le comentario de @Pikoh, edita tu pregunta y podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que comenta @PabloSimonDiEstefano es aún mas probable que lo que yo comentaba. Pero para asegurarnos, necesitamos ver algo de código, por ejemplo como llamas al formulario hijo y como accede éste al padre

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, no controlo mucho sobre el tema, estoy aprendiendo. Gracias por la ayuda. @Pikoh

Comment: Cuando dices que es un formulario hijo te refieres a que estas aplicando herencia? `Form2 : Form1` ???

Comment: Estuve probando a hacerlo con herencia y sin ella. No importa la herencia en este caso, gracias. @HectorLopez

Comment: Creo que el problema es el que te indicaba @PabloSimonDiEstefano. En el formulario hijo estás creando un nuevo formulario padre `frm2 = new Form2("false");` en lugar de hacer referencia al ya existente. Lo mejor es que en el hijo crees un constructor al que pases la referencia del padre, y sea en esa referencia en la que cambies el tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es muy habitual entre los principiantes en la programación,y se basa en la diferenciación entre una clase y una instancia.

Pongamos este ejemplo. Vamos a crear dos `Form2`:

```
Form2 frm1= new Form2();
Form2 frm2= new Form2();
```

Aqui lo que tenemos son dos instancias **diferentes** de `Form2`. Si hacemos lo siguiente:

```
frm1.Tag="prueba";
```

la única instancia afectada es la de `frm1`. Si consultamos `frm2.Tag` será `null`, ya que aunque la clase usada para crear el objeto es la misma `Form2`, los objetos son diferentes.

Aplicado a tu caso, cuando en tu formulario hijo tu haces `Form2 frm2; frm2 = new Form2("false");` estás creando una nueva instancia de `Form2`, y el tag no se modificará en el formulario padre existente, sino en este nuevo objeto, que va a desaparecer en el momento en el que desaparezca el formulario hijo.

Un solución muy sencilla es crear en el formulario hijo un constructor que reciba la instancia del padre, algo como:

```
Form2 formularioPadre;

public FormularioHijo(Form2 formulario)
{
    this.formularioPadre=formulario;
}
```

Y desde el formulario padre, a la hora de crear el hijo, usaríamos este nuevo constructor:

```
FormularioHijo frmHijo= new FormularioHijo(this);
frmHijo.Show();
```

De esta manera, en el formulario hijo en `formularioPadre` tendríamos ya un enlace a la instancia del formulario padre.

Para modificar el tag entonces, simplemente habría que hacer lo siguiente:

```
this.formularioPadre.Tag = false;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me ha ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar datos entre los formularios yo lo hago mediante métodos;

Si abres el formulario mediante el click en un botón (por ejemplo) puedes pasarle datos al nuevo formulario de esta manera;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.recuperarValores("Nuevo valor");
        f2.Show();
    }
```

Y el formulario 2 lo recuperara;

```
    public void recuperarValores(String valorRecuperado)
    {
        this.label1.Text = valorRecuperado;
        this.label1.Tag = valorRecuperado;
    }
```

En el caso que comentas tu lo quieres realizar al cerrarlo.

Tendrás que asegurarte de no crear una nueva instancia, ya que de esta manera estarás reseteando los valores;

`Form1`

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.recuperarValores("Nuevo valor");
        f2.Show();
    }

    public void RecuperarValorAlCerrar(string valor)
    {
        this.button1.Text = valor;
        this.button1.Tag = valor;
    }
```

`Form2`

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form ;
    public Form2(Form1 f)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form = f;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void recuperarValores(String valorRecuperado)
    {
        this.label1.Text = valorRecuperado;
        this.label1.Tag = valorRecuperado;
    }

    private void btnCerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form.RecuperarValorAlCerrar("Valor2");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

De esta manera estarás guardando en el form hijo la instancia del que lo ha invocado y asignaras el valor sin perderlo.